# Random seed choice changes qualitative results of elastic net parameter tuning, with Cox regression

Tags: cross-validation, cox-model, glmnet

Below is a function I wrote to try and tune the $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ elastic net GLM implemented with `cv.glmnet`. I've noticed that the qualitative outcome (in terms of the alpha that yields the lowest prediction error score) changes depending on the random seed, and I suspect this is mainly because the random seed determines how the folds are partitioned. In one of my datasets, I have only 598 samples and am fitting a Cox regression. That is where this effect is strongest (and, indeed, where the error bars about the prediction errors on the $\lambda$ search grid are largest). When I fit a binomial regression to a larger data set with about 30K observations, I get less jumping around. The number of folds doesn't seem to matter much.

I'm thinking of just choosing $\alpha$ = 0.5 in such cases, because the absolute difference in the cross-validation error scores are often quite small, and elastic net has inferential properties that make it more desirable that LASSO or ridge on their own.

Is this the right way of thinking? Thanks.

```
cvglmnet2a <- function(x, y, family, nfolds, seed) {
  set.seed(seed)
  cvfit0 <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family = family, alpha = 0, nfolds = nfolds)
  cvfitp5 <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family = family, alpha = 0.5, nfolds = nfolds)
  cvfit1 <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family = family, alpha = 1, nfolds = nfolds)
  plot(cvfit1); plot(cvfitp5); plot(cvfit0)
  plot(log(cvfit1$lambda), cvfit1$cvm,
       pch = 19, col = "red", xlab = "log(Lambda)", ylab = cvfit1$name)
      points(log(cvfitp5$lambda), cvfitp5$cvm, pch = 19, col = "grey")
      points(log(cvfit0$lambda), cvfit0$cvm, pch = 19, col = "blue")
      legend("topleft", legend = c("alpha = 1", "alpha = 0.5", "alpha = 0"),
             pch = 19, col = c("red", "grey", "blue"))
      mins <- c(alpha1 = min(cvfit1$cvm),
            alphap5 = min(cvfitp5$cvm),
                alpha0 = min(cvfit0$cvm))
  mins
}
```

Comment: This sounds specific to Cox regression, so tagged it so. Sorry I don't know anything about Cox regression. Maybe look at class imbalance (or whatever the equivalent is for Cox regression), turn on the `keep=T` parameter, look at `fit$foldid` and see how the fold assignment varies. *"choosing α = 0.5 because... absolute difference in the cross-validation error scores are often quite small"* - well please tell us some actual numbers.

Comment: The random seed changes the CV fold assignment, which obviously changes everything in your model, even with the stabilizing effect of alpha. Whether Cox regression is any more sensitive to that than other families, I don't know (show us some numbers! for Cox vs other families). The usual advice is try many random seeds and pick the ones with lowest CV score, or average their coefficients.

Comment: Of your 598 samples in the Cox regression, how many had events as opposed to censoring?